# Arduino : avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino-uno

I'm currently trying to make Controlling an RGB LED With an Android Smartphone Using Arduino and Bluetooth Module. As in below link tutorial.

> http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-an-RGB-LED-With-an-Android-Smartphone-/

I'm using Arduino Uno.
I made as in tutorial and code and upload to Arduino then It's Show as below Error Messages and cannot upload to Arduino.

```
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:01:35
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/
     Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     User configuration file is "/Users/kyawzinwai/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, 
     skipping

     Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem1421
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200

     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: 
     resp=0x00
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync:                   
     resp=0x00
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: 
     resp=0x00
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: 
     resp=0x00
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: 
     resp=0x00
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: 
     resp=0x00
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: 
     resp=0x00
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: 
     resp=0x00
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: 
     resp=0x00
     avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
     avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: 
     resp=0x00

     avrdude done.  Thank you.

     Problem uploading to board.  See 
     http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for 
     suggestions.
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally I can solve the problem. Remove all wire from Arduino Dev Board and Just upload the sketch only to the dev board and when upload done. Reconnect all the wires again and Done.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can have various reasons, please refer the link below

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won

If you are a mac user, please see this link
[Mac + Uno + avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993111/mac-uno-avrdude-stk500-recv-programmer-is-not-responding)

Comment: Thanks you for your reply bro. I can solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help somebody...
I got this same error "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding" because my COM port was not properly connected even though it was showing as my board connected with COM1 port. My details are Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

I had to **disable driver signature enforcement in windows 8.1** after that I installed drivers from device manager.Once I restarted my PC then only COM4 was displayed in ports list in Arduino IDE.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the "programmer is not responding" error when I tried to flash my attiny85. I got rid of the annoying error when I switched to Arduino IDE 1.6.4 and chose the Arduino Genuino/ Uno as board. That's the important part and a common error: don't switch to "Arduino as ISP" mode when you upload the example sketch named "ArduinoISP".
And another thing to remember is to use the right capacitor. I first used a 1000mF cap and thought it could work but I was wrong. Use something in the 10mf - 100mF range.

Thanks for your attention, Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had Arduino (UNO) pin0 and pin1 connected to a seven segments display.
Pin 0 and 1 are used in the upload communication. Before upload remove pin 0 and 1 and reset them after upload. Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure RESET and GND pins of Arduino are not

Comment: What? Are not what?