# Can't upload to arduino Uno board. Error message - avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to upload a simple sketch to my Uno board but get this error message:
**avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding.**

I have 5 Uno boards and 3 of them works fine so I guess it is something to do specifically with the two boards (which used to work) and not my system or cables.

I also did a loop-back test (http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=73748.0) on both of the boards where one worked fine and the other didn't echoed back.

I read about possible solutions for this problem in the following link but being new to arduino I couldn't figure out how to debug the problems or how to implement some of the solutions.
[Arduino Sketch upload issue - avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765037/arduino-sketch-upload-issue-avrdude-stk500-recv-programmer-is-not-respondi)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

edit: Tried using an Arduino as an AVR ISP but failed with both of the boards (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP)

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug. Try to disconnect all peripheral from arduino pins. And repeat uploading sketch.

Comment: There are no peripherals.
It's a known error message which means that generally something is not working, it seems that on both of the boards the problem wont be fixed by disconnecting re-plugging or restarting..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Mega328P or the Mega 32u4(?) chip or both are blown. I had one once and it was pretty much as you described - in my case the Mega28P was partially blown due to a short circuit and, its a bit difficult to describe, but it sort of got more erratic over time before it stopped working completely.

As for the Mega328P, many Uno's mount them in a socket, so you could try switching the 328P MCU from a "not working one" to a "working board" and see if the "working board" stops working, the "non working board" starts working and so on.

I think this could also occur if the bootloader is corrupt or missing, but I think you tried to address that, but perhaps double check this procedure:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/ArduinoISP