# Arduino error, how to fix?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x02
```

What is this error, how can I fix it?

Comment: Arduino Uno, Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

please use this topic to go through all the suggested solutions, trying to reset the arduino at x seconds, updating your ftdi drivers, etc

[Arduino Sketch upload issue - avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765037/arduino-sketch-upload-issue-avrdude-stk500-recv-programmer-is-not-respondi)