# Arduino Nano programmer not responding

Tags: arduino, arduino-nano

I recently bought a Nano, and when I try uploading the code, it throws this error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

Sketch uses 924 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.

Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x03

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I have tried changing the programmer, changing the processor to the old bootloader; all of the standard stuff. Nothing has worked.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could we see your code? Also, are you using any other app that could be messing with your COM ports (Processing, for example - using serial)?

Comment: It is just the basic blink sketch, and I don't think anything is messing with the COM ports

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arduino Sketch upload issue - avrdude: stk500\_recv(): programmer is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765037/arduino-sketch-upload-issue-avrdude-stk500-recv-programmer-is-not-respondi)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue with IDE 2.0.3 and had to go to tools/Processor/ATmega328P (Old Bootloader).

This changed the bitrate from 115200 to 57600 and allowed the nano to be programmed.

Answer (score 0):

Test other ports, and other USB cable. If you buy this nano from China, maybe it has CH3040 usb driver (this is a cheap chinese usb communication chip). If that's true, download this [driver](https://sparks.gogo.co.nz/ch340.html), without that isn't work chinese nano.

Comment: I bought the nano from thePiHut, so I’m not sure if I still need the driver, but I did try to install it and it says it already is

Answer (score -1):

Arduino Nano Uses the CH340G driver unlike the CP2102 used in UNO
so you need to install the correct drivers and check inside drivers section for the COM port  .
If you have already burnt the new bootloader it wont cause any upload issues

As a last resort  you can use Arduino as ISP to program your NAno
please check  out this  [article](https://www.instructables.com/Programming-Arduino-Nano-Using-UNO/)

Comment: The official Arduino Nano uses FTDI FT232RL not CH340G. And the official Arduino Uno uses ATmega16U2 not CP2102.