# Error "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding" (macOS Monterey)

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, macos-monterey

Recently, I started a project using an Arduino Uno. I am using the Arduino IDE on macOS v12.2 (Monterey). The IDE was compiling and uploading to the Arduino fine; however, recently it still compiles, but keeps sending me the "programmer is not responding error" when uploading.

Below is my code and the steps I have taken to debug so far.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(1000);
  delay(50);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Hello, World!");
  delay(500);
}
```

- First, I tried unplugging, replugging, and resetting my board.
- I also made sure that the correct port and board were selected in the IDE.
- Furthermore, I deleted the IDE completely and reinstalled it.
- Lastly, I switched out the board and wire for other ones and the error still remained.

None of these seem to be the issue as I tested the same program and board on a Windows laptop and it uploaded fine. Additionally, the RX light flashes every couple of seconds and the L light is constantly on, showing proper connectivity. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the macOS and Arduino IDE specifically.

Comment: This is a *very* common problem (due to the ill-defined (too slow) reset signal from the RC circuit without a Schmitt trigger). For [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers) it is so common that the standard procedure is to ***double*** click on the reset button on the board before flashing. Then you have about 8 seconds to start the flash process (so be ready; e.g., have compilation done with Ctrl + R beforehand). (A single click does not leave enough time. The exact behaviour may depend on the bootloader, incl. version.)

Comment: There *must* be a canonical for this question.

Comment: Candidate: *[Arduino Sketch upload issue - avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765037/)*. It contains a long list of what could be wrong (though nothing directly about the double click on the reset button).

Comment: Though it may not apply to the Arduino Uno.

Comment: After a lot of testing, it turns out it is just macOS that doesn't allow for the connection anymore with the latest software. The Arduino ended up not being the problem and I even went as far as redownloading drivers and such, which didn't work. Ended up just using a Rasberry Pi to run arudino IDE and compile/upload code.